# Produce a report of all devices connected to my home network using Terminal

Tags: networking, command-line

Using my home router's UI (Netgear Genie, accessible at [www.routerlogin.com](http://www.routerlogin.com)), I am able to view an HTML page showing all devices connected to my network. Information shown on this page includes:

- Network SSIDs
- Connected devices

  - IPv4 and IPv6 address
  - MAC address
  - Device name (which doesn't appear to match hostname)

I just don't want to log into a browser application every time I want to see this report.

**Is there a combination of command-line tools available on Mac OS that will get me the same information that my router is pulling?**

Comment: nmap is one very popular option, but you will want to experiment with the scan types to determine what is best for you. https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html

Comment: You could script the connection with `curl` for example.